# Files a VB.net application uses

Tags: vb.net

In a VB application I have created, co-ordinate points are written to a KML file for use in Google Earth. In order use this application on another computer I believe I would have to create an installer with a folder with all the files, including the two KMLs, that the program will need? Is there a way to tell the program to retrieve the files from an installation folder if the program was installed using a setup wizard?

I had read and tried this code but to no avail:

```
Dim loc = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
Dim appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(loc)
Dim appName = Path.GetFileName(loc)
```

I also use this code to read and write the lines into the KML file.

```
Dim lineS() As Object = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\James\Documents\North Atlantic Tracks Project\North Atlantic Tracks\North Atlantic Tracks\test.kml")

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Users\James\Documents\North Atlantic Tracks Project\North Atlantic Tracks\North Atlantic Tracks\test.kml", lineS)
```

Many thanks

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a bare minimum, you need your executable, the Dlls it links to that aren't in the .Net framework and optionally the `.exe.config` file (if you use it for anything).

That said, there are better ways to do this. Consider using a [setup package](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&checkda=1&ct=1404420734&rver=6.2.6289.0&wp=LBI&wreply=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsofttranslator.com%2Fajax%2Fv2%2Fauth.aspx%3Fpru%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fdefault.aspx%2Fkb%2F307353&lc=2057&id=288908) which will handle install and put an entry in Programs & Features to uninstall.

Really it depends if you want a professional product or a way to share it with others.

Comment: I tried the publish option in VB but it kept failing to install. And both of the .exe files in Release and Debug aren't working either. I wondered if this was causing that problem?

Comment: Ok... Switch to debug profile, then Build->Clean Solution, Build->Rebuild Solution. Do you get any errors? If not, press the Run button and check your app launches, then browse to the `bin/Debug` folder and try running the executable from there (not the `.vshost` one). There should be no reason it runs from the IDE but not windows explorer.

Comment: Note that the project type I linked is very different from Click-once publishing from the project page. It creates a fully customisable installer

Comment: I'm not seeing that "Rebuild Solution" anywhere I'm afraid. I have VB2008 Express if that helps?

Comment: It should look something like [this VS2008 screenshot](http://www.tenouk.com/Winsock/visualstudio2008ncnwinsock2_files/winsock2visualstudiocplus010.png). Edit: I've always used Pro or Ultimate. [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/443bf510-0ff6-4c9c-a6f6-4bcdb587d285/clean-solution-for-vs-express?forum=csharpide) implies you might need to add the menu item manually and/or switch to expert mode